# Need EF workaround to only load totals and not every row

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

The following query runs without error.

```
var results = await query
    .GroupBy(
        t => new { t.Departure!.Value.Year, t.Departure!.Value.Month },
        t => new
        {
            Departure = t.Departure!.Value,
            Quantity = t.InboundQuantity + t.TruckRailcars.Sum(tr => tr.Quantity) + t.StorageTrucks.Sum(st => st.Quantity)
        })
    .ToListAsync();
```

However, this query returns some 50,000 rows. But all I need are the totals, which are 12 rows. So I tried adding a `Select()` clause.

```
var results = await query
    .GroupBy(
        t => new { t.Departure!.Value.Year, t.Departure!.Value.Month },
        t => new
        {
            Departure = t.Departure!.Value,
            Quantity = t.InboundQuantity + t.TruckRailcars.Sum(tr => tr.Quantity) + t.StorageTrucks.Sum(st => st.Quantity)
        })
    .Select(g => new { Date = g.Key, Quantity = g.Sum(t => t.Quantity) })
    .ToListAsync();
```

But this fails.

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'

I've tried every variation of this I could think of, but no luck. It would be horribly inefficient to receive all 50,000 rows when all I need are the totals. Does anyone here have any ideas?

*Note: `query` is simply a database table with a couple of `Where()` clauses.*

**Update**

If anyone's curious, here's the query generated by the accepted answer.

```sql
SELECT [t5].[Year], [t5].[Month], COALESCE(SUM([t5].[Quantity]), 0.0E0) AS [Quantity]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Year], [t0].[Month], COALESCE(SUM([t0].[InboundQuantity]), 0.0E0) AS [Quantity]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t].[InboundQuantity], DATEPART(year, [t].[Departure]) AS [Year], DATEPART(month, [t].[Departure]) AS [Month]
        FROM [Trucks] AS [t]
        INNER JOIN [Facilities] AS [f] ON [t].[FacilityId] = [f].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [Companies] AS [c] ON [f].[CompanyId] = [c].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [PurchaseOrders] AS [p] ON [t].[PurchaseOrderId] = [p].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [Products] AS [p0] ON [p].[ProductId] = [p0].[Id]
        WHERE [c].[CompanyCode] = @__companyCode_0 AND [t].[Departure] >= @__startMonth_1 AND [t].[Departure] < @__endMonth_2 AND [p0].[UnitOfMeasurement] = 0 AND [t].[FacilityId] = 1
    ) AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[Year], [t0].[Month]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [t2].[Year], [t2].[Month], COALESCE(SUM([t2].[Quantity]), 0.0E0) AS [Quantity]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t4].[Quantity], DATEPART(year, [t3].[Departure]) AS [Year], DATEPART(month, [t3].[Departure]) AS [Month]
        FROM [Trucks] AS [t3]
        INNER JOIN [Facilities] AS [f0] ON [t3].[FacilityId] = [f0].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [Companies] AS [c0] ON [f0].[CompanyId] = [c0].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [PurchaseOrders] AS [p1] ON [t3].[PurchaseOrderId] = [p1].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [Products] AS [p2] ON [p1].[ProductId] = [p2].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [TruckRailcars] AS [t4] ON [t3].[Id] = [t4].[TruckId]
        WHERE [c0].[CompanyCode] = @__companyCode_0 AND [t3].[Departure] >= @__startMonth_1 AND [t3].[Departure] < @__endMonth_2 AND [p2].[UnitOfMeasurement] = 0 AND [t3].[FacilityId] = 1
    ) AS [t2]
    GROUP BY [t2].[Year], [t2].[Month]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [t6].[Year], [t6].[Month], COALESCE(SUM([t6].[Quantity]), 0.0E0) AS [Quantity]
    FROM (
        SELECT [s].[Quantity], DATEPART(year, [t7].[Departure]) AS [Year], DATEPART(month, [t7].[Departure]) AS [Month]
        FROM [Trucks] AS [t7]
        INNER JOIN [Facilities] AS [f1] ON [t7].[FacilityId] = [f1].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [Companies] AS [c1] ON [f1].[CompanyId] = [c1].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [PurchaseOrders] AS [p3] ON [t7].[PurchaseOrderId] = [p3].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [Products] AS [p4] ON [p3].[ProductId] = [p4].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [StorageTrucks] AS [s] ON [t7].[Id] = [s].[TruckId]
        WHERE [c1].[CompanyCode] = @__companyCode_0 AND [t7].[Departure] >= @__startMonth_1 AND [t7].[Departure] < @__endMonth_2 AND [p4].[UnitOfMeasurement] = 0 AND [t7].[FacilityId] = 1
    ) AS [t6]
    GROUP BY [t6].[Year], [t6].[Month]
) AS [t5]
GROUP BY [t5].[Year], [t5].[Month]
```

Comment: You could push this work to the database by using a view or stored procedure.  GROUP BY to get the totals, then just call the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be splitted by three parts and grouped again after concatenation.

```cs
var inbound =
    from t in query
    group t by new { t.Departure!.Value.Year, t.Departure!.Value.Month } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key,
        Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.InboundQuantity)
    };

var truckRailcars =
    from t in query
    from tr in t.TruckRailcars
    group tr by new { t.Departure!.Value.Year, t.Departure!.Value.Month } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key,
        Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    };

var storageTrucks =
    from t in query
    from st in t.StorageTrucks
    group st by new { t.Departure!.Value.Year, t.Departure!.Value.Month } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key,
        Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    };

var resultQuery = 
    from q in inbound.Concat(truckRailcars).Concat(storageTrucks)
    group q by q.Key into g
    select new 
    {
        Date = g.Key,
        Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    };
```

**Variant 2**

**Ivan Stoev** forced me to generate another variant. Performannce should be compared by enalysing execution plan and execution time:

```cs
var resultQuery =
    from t in query
    select new 
    {
        Year = t.Departure!.Value.Year,
        Month = t.Departure!.Value.Month,

        InboundQuantity = t.InboundQuantity,

        TruckrailCars = t.TruckRailcars.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
        StorageTrucks = t.StorageTrucks.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
    } into s
    group s by new { s.Year, s.Month } into g
    select new 
    {
        Date = g.Key,
        Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.InboundQuantity + x.TruckrailCars + x.StorageTrucks)
    };
```

**Variant 3**

Variant with LEFT joins

```cs
var inbound =
    from t in query
    from tr in t.TruckRailcars.GroupBy(x => 1)
        .Select(g => new { Quantity = g.Sum(g => g.Quantity) } )
        .DefauIfEmpty()
    from st in t.StorageTrucks.GroupBy(x => 1)
        .Select(g => new { Quantity = g.Sum(g => g.Quantity) } )
        .DefauIfEmpty()
    group {t.InboundQuantity, tr, st } by new { t.Departure!.Value.Year, t.Departure!.Value.Month } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key,
        Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.InboundQuantity + x.tr.Quantity + x.st.Quantity)
    };
```

Comment: I'm completely blown away that this runs! Would you mind explaining a little why this would run but my original code doesn't?

Comment: In short, you have used collection navigation properties inside GroupBy projection.  There is no direct SQL translation for such queries. EF is trying to do something but fails when complexity grows. I have looked at this problem from data perspective and imagined how it should looks like in SQL. Then simple LINQ implementation.

Comment: @JonathanWood EF Core query translator defect/bug. Above is workaround fooling/forcing the translator to generate inefficient, but proper SQL. The main problem is that they are trying to optimize too much, moving some expressions out of the inner SQL subquery, which makes the final SQL invalid. Simply bug.

Comment: @IvanStoev, actually yes, it is possible to translate with two LEFT JOINs. I have to check how it will works with new `linq2db` translator which I'm implementing, At first sight it should.

Comment: @IvanStoev: That's unfortunate. However, probably much more efficient than retrieving all 50,000 rows and grouping them on the client.

Comment: @IvanStoev and why inefficient? I thought I have prepared best query in such case. Probably you have better idea?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Of course. Just need a way to push the two sums inside the subquery.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: Thanks for the workaround. If you're curious, I've added the generated SQL to my question--in case anyone's curious.

Comment: @JonathanWood, well then try another variant, which I have added to  the question.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: Thanks, but unfortunately the second variant produces the same error.